How to Issue Refunds to Store Credit via Magento API?
I’m using Magento 2 Commerce (EE) on Adobe Commerce Cloud and want to issue refunds to a customer’s store credit balance programmatically via the REST API. While I know that store credit functionality is supported natively in Magento Commerce (e.g., refunds to store credit through the admin panel), I’m unable to find a single API endpoint to handle this use case.
Here’s what I’ve tried so far:
I attempted to use the POST /V1/creditmemo/refund API with the following payload:
{
  "items": [
    {
      "item_id": "item",
      "qty": 1
    }
  ],
  "is_online": true,
  "notify": true,
  "arguments": {
    "shipping_amount": 0,
    "adjustment_positive": 2,
    "adjustment_negative": 1
  }
}


Take a look at https://magecomp.com/blog/issue-refund-credit-memo-using-api-magento-2/

no sir its allow to return only amount which pay by card. in case "Store credit" and "reward point"  its not providing
